# PHP no me muestra errores en la conexion aunque esta sea incorrecta

Tags: php, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente codigo que realiza la conexión de php y sql server pero  aunque yo ponga los datos de la conexión mal no me muestra ningún error:

```
<?php session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
    header('location: contenido.php');
}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $nombre=FILTER_VAR(strtolower($_POST['nombre']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $usuario=strtolower($_POST['usuario']);
    $mail=strtolower($_POST['mail']);
    $pass=$_POST['pass'];
    $pass2=$_POST['pass2'];

    /*Imprimimos los datos para ver que todo funcione correctamente 
    echo $nombre . '<br/>' . $usuario . '<br/>' . $mail . '<br/>' . $pass . '<br/>' . $pass2; */
    $errores='';

    if (empty($nombre) or empty($usuario) or empty($mail) or empty($pass) or empty($pass2)) {
        $errores .= '<li>Debes rellenar todos los campos</li>';
    }else{
        try{
            $servidor='(LOCAL)';
            $base='login_usuos';
            $usuario='sa';
            $password='password';

            $conexion=new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$servidor;Database=$base", "$usuario", "$password");
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo "Error en la conexion:" . $e->getMessage();
        }
$query="SELECT * FROM t_usuarios WHERE usuario= :usuario LIMIT 1";
    $statement=sqlsrv_prepare($conexion, $query, array(':usuario' => $usuario));
    $resultado=sqlsrv_execute($statement);
    $row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultado);
    }
}
require 'vistas/registro.view.php';

?>
```

Podrían decirme porqué y si tengo algo mal para corregirlo ?

Comment: En que entorno estas desarrollando, XAMPP o estas en linux??

Comment: Estoy utilizando XAMPP

Answer (score 1):

Si colocás un "or die()" después de cada petición que hagas a la base de datos, el error aparece automaticamente. Y si los archivos que utilizás son php's llamados por un js (por medio de ajax), la manera de ver un error es haciendo un console.log(respuesta) o un alert(respuesta). Trabajo todo el tiempo con envios de datos a su respectiva base de datos y las respuestas al ajax, y es la manera que me funciona para detectar errores.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php 

require 'vistas/registro.view.php';
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
    header('location: contenido.php');
}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $nombre=FILTER_VAR(strtolower($_POST['nombre']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $usuario=strtolower($_POST['usuario']);
    $mail=strtolower($_POST['mail']);
    $pass=$_POST['pass'];
    $pass2=$_POST['pass2'];

    /*Imprimimos los datos para ver que todo funcione correctamente 
    echo $nombre . '<br/>' . $usuario . '<br/>' . $mail . '<br/>' . $pass . '<br/>' . $pass2; */
    $errores='';

    if (empty($nombre) or empty($usuario) or empty($mail) or empty($pass) or empty($pass2)) {
        $errores .= '<li>Debes rellenar todos los campos</li>';
    }else{
        try{
            $servidor='(LOCAL)';
            $base='login_usuos';
            $usuario='sa';
            $password='password';

            $conexion=new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$servidor;Database=$base", "$usuario", "$password");
            //debes utilizar manejadores de errores
            $conexion->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); //prueba utilizando esto amigo
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo "Error en la conexion:" . $e->getMessage();
        }
    $query="SELECT * FROM t_usuarios WHERE usuario= :usuario LIMIT 1";
    $statement=sqlsrv_prepare($conexion, $query, array(':usuario' => $usuario));
    $resultado=sqlsrv_execute($statement);
    $row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultado);
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte amigo, pero no funciona. Si lo pongo separado en otra página funciona correctamente: <?php 

try{
    $servidor='(LOCAL)';
    $base='login_usuarios';
    $usuario='sa';
    $password='admin01';

    $conexion=new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$servidor;Database=$base", "$usuario", "$password");
   }catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Error en la conexion:" . $e->getMessage(). "\n";
     exit;
  }
  

 ?>